# Need to use Custom EditText in Android

Tags: android

Is there any custom edit text available for android. i need some nice layout like in iphone. The edit text of iphone looks better than android... is there any way we can make android's edittext better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       <EditText android:id="@+id/etNote" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip" android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/img_border"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:gravity="top"        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Changed your background image as per your design.